# Adjusting cmd_vel linear.y value published by move_base

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following action-client code which I use to send a pose to move_base which inturn  moves my robot model.

```
def move(self, goal):
    rospy.loginfo(goal)
    client_mb = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('move_base', MoveBaseAction)
    client_mb.wait_for_server()

    pose = Pose(Point(goal.x, goal.y, goal.z), Quaternion(0.000, 0.000, 0.0, 1.0))
    
    # Set up the next goal location
    self.goal = MoveBaseGoal()
    self.goal.target_pose.pose = pose
    self.goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = 'map'
    self.goal.target_pose.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    
    # Let the user know where the robot is going next
    rospy.loginfo("Going to: " + str(goal))
    feedback_obj = TakePositionFeedback()
    feedback_obj.report = 'Moving to: ' + str(goal.position)
    self._as.publish_feedback(feedback_obj)
    
    # Start the robot toward the next location
    client_mb.send_goal(self.goal)
    client_mb.wait_for_result()
```

The robot successfully moves to the specified destination.

But, **I'm looking for a means of instructing the robot to move on the left or righ hand side of a corridor while travelling to the destination.** The idea is to read the laser sensors on the right side of the robot, determin the distance to the wall and get the robot to drive parrallel to the wall maintaining a specified maximum distance. The same would apply to the left.

I can see data being published to **/cmd_vel** but I'm not sure how or if it's possible to preempt the linear.y value on the fly.

Any help please ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376425/adjusting-cmd_vel-linear.y-value-published-by-move_base/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2021-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may be able to move it by changing the value of cmd_vel in the following.

1. Use remap and make cmd_vel of move_base a different name. ( For  example, cmd_vel_origin )
2. Create a node that subscribes to cmd_vel_origin, updates its value, and publishes it.
3. Move the created node together with move_base

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-04-21**:
@Miura: Hi nad thanks for your answer. You were completely right. That was infact what I was attempting. I remapped **cmd_vel** to **cmd_vel_original** in the mode_base node of my launch file.
However, I have serious issues when I subscrided to *cmd_vel_original*, overwrote the value of **twist.angular.z** and published to *cmd_vel*.
My robot did not move smoothly towards the wall edge as I hoped. It just does a very disorganized looking rotation on the spot.
I have been reshearching and it seems the kind on problem a PID would solve but I don't know how to implement one. Is this something that the [pid](http://wiki.ros.org/pid) package can be used for and if so how ?

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-04-21**:
I'm glad I could be of some help.

Sorry, I'm not familiar with the pid package.
However, on a general topic, I think PID is a way to smoothly bridge the gap between the target and current values. If the target and current values are defined in overriding the twist.angular.z, may the PID package is going to be effective.

Since the question is changing from the content of the question, I would recommend creating another question.